# Url Rewrite to redirect any js to a common folder

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm using isapi_rewrite3

The following are examples

- /extfile/banner.js
- /home/home/foo.js
- /this/that/file.js

have all been physically moved to

- /include/js/*.js

How do I write a redirect that will redirect any request to any js file to the new single directory? I want to do the same for css as well.

Here is what I have so far. I feel like I am getting pretty close, but I am probably making it overly complicated.

`RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.(js|css)$ /include/$2/$1.$2  [NC]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was correct `RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.(js|css)$ /include/$2/$1.$2 [NC]`.